# Как использовать onBackPressed в MainFragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Не понимаю, как актуально на сегодняшний день переопределить OnBackpressed что бы использовать в фрагментах.

Answer (score 3):

Для этого есть `OnBackPressedCallback`. Добавьте в `onViewCreated`.

`Kotlin`:

```
val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        // обработайте здесь
    }
}

 activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, callback)
```

`Java`:

```
   OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true ) {
    @Override
    public void handleOnBackPressed() {
        // обработайте здесь
    }
};
requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(getViewLifecycleOwner(), callback);
```

Comment: Подчеркивает requireActivity и getViewLifecycleOwner красным. Проект пробовал чистить, пересобирать. Не помогло.

Comment: @Иван проверил все работает у меня. что именно пишет студия?

Comment: cannot resolve method "requireActivity" in "MainFragment" и cannot resolve method "getViewLifecycleOwner" и in "MainFragment"

Comment: @Иван Androidx подключен? если нет то мигрируйте проект на androidx https://stackoverflow.com/a/54965043/8389574

Comment: Да, я делал миграцию на androidx. Так же студия импортировала мне:import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback;

Comment: @Иван тогда хз почему. попробуйте обновить все версии зависимостей в gradle. может какая из версий старая стоит

Comment: или на котлин ковертируйте фрагмент

Comment: Обновлял, конверт на котлин не помог.

Comment: на котлине на что ругается?

Comment: Тоже самое. Не определяет метод

Comment: на котлине на viewLifecycleOwner ругается что ли? и на activity? да не может быть

Comment: Подчеркивает красным и выдает Unresolved reference: onBackPressedDispatcher и viewLifecycleOwner при этом перечекривает activity? перед .onBackPressedDispatcher

Comment: Убрав все импорты мне удалось понять что скорей всего дело было в `import android.app.Fragment;` с `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;` все прекрасно работает, но стало жаловаться на `.add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())` - error: no suitable method found for add(int,MainFragment) .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())   ^
   method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment) method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; MainFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)